# How can I write data to the App_Data folder in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-web-api, app-data

I can write data to the App_Data folder in my ASP.NET Web API app like so:

```
string appDataFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
var htmlStr = // method that returns html as a string
string htmlFilename = "platypus.html";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, htmlFilename);
File.WriteAllText(fullPath, htmlStr);
```

I want to do something similar in an ASP.NET MVC app (the data is different - a PDF file instead of an html file), but "File" is not recognized. I try this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
. . .
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
string appDataFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
string pdfFilename = "test.pdf";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, pdfFilename);
File.WriteAllText(fullPath, bytes);
```

...but get, "*'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context'*"

In the first place, I don't think my code is what the err msg seems to indicate it is, but nevertheless it's not accepted, so: how *can* I write data to the App_Data folder in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Try fully qualifying `File` -> `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`

Comment: Yes, that did it; odd that that wasn't an option/offered or suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a namespace collision. The compiler is grabbing `File` from a different namespace than is expected. The `File` class that should make this work is in the `System.IO` namespace and not the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` namespace.

This can be fixed by explicitly specifying the correct namespace when calling `File.WriteAllText()`:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath, bytes);
```